# Google Cloud and .net core

Tags: google-app-engine, .net-core, google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to host .net core console application on Google Cloud Platform?
I would like to have something similar to Windows service but on Google Cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are 3 ways to run .NET core applications on Google Cloud Platform.

If you'd like to run your .NET core applications in Linux containers instead of Windows, you can use [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/) or [Google Container Engine](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-kubernetes-aspnetcore/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0).

You can also run .NET (any) applications on Windows instances in Google Compute Engine.  This [sample](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/hello-world) gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following page from Google Cloud documentation. It describes how to run Windows and Windows Applications on Compute Engine

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/